# Java.Net.SocketException Error: Socket closed in System.net.Http httpClient, occurs only when sending files larger than 50kbs

Tags: http, xamarin

I am making a program in xamarin, which uses http requests to get data from an API made in net.core 2.0, but some requests (most of them actually) culminate in the following error:

```
  System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Java.Net.SocketException: Socket closed
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualInt32Method (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
  at Java.Net.HttpURLConnection.get_ResponseCode () [0x0000a] in <b781ed64f1d743e7881ac038e0fbdf85>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass45_0.<DoProcessRequest>b__1 () [0x00000] in <b781ed64f1d743e7881ac038e0fbdf85>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<DoProcessRequest>d__45.MoveNext () [0x0036c] in <b781ed64f1d743e7881ac038e0fbdf85>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__40.MoveNext () [0x00230] in <b781ed64f1d743e7881ac038e0fbdf85>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0000f] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at FonoApp.Services.DataService.SendImageAsync (System.String token, FonoApp.Model.Imagem imagem) [0x00059] in C:\Projetos Sorri\FonoApp\AppTeste\AppTeste\Services\DataService.cs:154 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}
```

This error occurs in this code snippet:

```
public async Task<String> SendImage(string token, Imagem imagem)
        {
            string baseAddress = @"http://192.168.0.4:5000/" + VersaoApi + @"/Imagem/";
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imagem);
            var contentString = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = client.PostAsync(baseAddress, contentString).Result;//Erro ocorre nesta linha
                var jsonContent = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return jsonContent;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.InnerException.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

From what I researched, and discovered from this error, means that the connection is being closed either by the server or by the client, but I can't even know who closes the connection suddenly let alone prevent this / exception error, I don't know if it matters but I am testing the app on an android 4.2-API 17 tablet. Thanks in advance for any guidance on this as I am still learning how to program in C #.
one thing I forgot to say before was that Postman API requests work without problems

I noticed something interesting the error I get only occurs when trying to send images larger than 100 kb by http request, how can I increase the send and receive weight limit on my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use await instead of Result() to make this method async:

```
 var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And yes, this exception occurs when internet connection is lost. You can do these things to make your app more usable:

1. Display a warning message in try-catch block
2. Check internet connection by using Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity plugin
3. Set a timeout for your HttpClient object and catch the TimeoutException to display proper message

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I made the changes you told me, and when testing the network with xamarin.Essentials.Connectvy I found that the error does not occur due to internet crash, as xamarin.Essentials.Connectvy's Connectivity.NetworkAccess always shows that I have a network. internet and when checking my tablet I also notice that it has a strong and stable network connection

Comment: I noticed something interesting the error I get only occurs when trying to send images larger than 100 kb by http request, how can I increase the send and receive weight limit on my server?

Comment: You need the set client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue for getting bigger files from your server.

Comment: and to send large files to the server, for example i have a 10kb image that always works send by http post, but the other one of 120kbs always ends up in the task was canceled error, sendi as well as sending large files?